# How should I load/unload JS called by dynamically loaded partial pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I make use of *jQuery* and *history.js* to manage dynamic transitions between partial-pages; such that I avoid reloading entire documents. Some of these partial-pages call their own unique *javascript* files. While the transitions between pages work well, remnants of executed *javascript* remain active after the partial page that called it has been dynamically replaced.

**How can I unload *javascript* that was introduced with a dynamic page load, and later asynchronously replaced by another page?**

## *The finer details*

### Master template

My **master template** (used for all pages) can be thought of as a simple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    //scripts to manage asynchronous loading of partial-pages into #content div
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### User profile

One partial page that renders inside the **#content** div is for a user's **Profile**:

```
<script src="profile.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="file" name="profile-picture">
</form>
```

The contents of **profile.js** are similar to:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').change(function() {
        // upload profile picture asynchronously
    });
});
```

### User settings

Another partial page that is loaded inside the **#content** div of the **master template** is the user's **Settings**:

```
<script src="settings.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="first-name">
    <input type="text" name="last-name">
</form>
```

The contents of **settings.js** are similar to:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // auto-submit form every 10 seconds
        $('form').submit();
    }, 10000);
}
});
```

### The problems

- Certain *javascript* functions continue to run (e.g. **setInterval**) after the partial page that called them has been replaced by another.
- This business of loading new *javascript* for each partial page feels messy; but for the life of me, I can't find any recommendations for best practices.

**What is the better way to achieve this effect of dynamic partial-page loading/unloading while allowing page-specific scripts for each partial page?**

Thank you!

Comment: Definitely clear your intervals as the answers below have suggested.  I guess what you're looking for is some secret way of unloading javascript from memory. There isn't one that I'm aware of. Create "class instantiations" per page then set their references to null when you're done. This should allow garbage collection to remove them from memory.  This is similar to what @charlie suggested near the end of his answer.

Comment: @JaredGotte Cool idea! Something like _var Settings = (function() ..._  Then null *Settings* when loading in a new page?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if that syntax instantiates anything.  I'm still learning JavaScript.  I had in mind something like `var Settings = new ClassName(...` then keeping track where you use Settings.  When you're done, set all of the references you have of Settings to null.  I guess `Settings = null` would even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly...once you load javascript...you can't unload it

The `setInterval` problem will require using `clearInterval`

Declare some esoteric name that would make it fairly unique as a global variable when you initialize `setiIterval;` Make sure you declare the `var` outside of `$(document).ready` before using it

var my_super_form_submitter

```
$(document.ready)function(){...
 my_super_form_submitter=setInterval(func.....
```

Then whenever you load a new page

```
if(my_super_form_submitter)
clearInterval(my_super_form_submitter)
```

As for collisions with other methods....you could adopt a content class protocol for your page specific code. On each page load, change class of content div...then use that class within selectors for jQuery

Comment: Using a content class in selectors would let me combine js from different pages without too much difficulty. What are your thoughts on maybe storing all the js in one network request?

Comment: Really depends on size of application and js size. Compare one file with all your script to size of jQuery file and compare based on that perhaps

Answer (score 0):

For first problem:

Question is what functions continues to run after replacing packages. SetInterval that you mentioned uses js timers, and simply replacing package wont stop timer automatically.
You should clear all timers started via setInterval before replacing.

E.g.

```
$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        // auto-submit form every 10 seconds
        $('form').submit();
    }, 10000);
}

function uninitialize(){
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Just call uninitialize before replacing package, and it should work.

UnfortunatelyI don't know any proper way for loading partial pages, but I hope it helps you somehow (:

Comment: simple solution; I like!